# Magento 2 how to add Conditions cart ruls Fieldset add in custom module

Tags: magento2.2

I am create module in magento 2 ,in which i want to add field "cart rule selecter" in admin module tab. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

[View Design Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvn11.png)